# Problems with making JavaScript quiz 1Q per page

Tags: javascript

I'm a teacher and have just starting to code recently. I need to make an online quiz for my students and I have been trying to find some script here and there to make the quiz that we want.

I've tried to find the solution online and I've seen people saying we can make one question per page by hiding the other question when the user clicks the "submit" button or add jquery etc. But I don't know where should I put the script and I've tried a few times but then it messed up my quiz.

Is there anyone who can help me to make it to a one-question-per-page quiz and also randomize the questions displayed to the users every time they attept to do the quiz?

Here's my quiz:

```js
 answer_list = [
      ["is,was"],
      ["Present tense"],
      ['is','was'],
      ['are','were','used to be'],
      ['am']
    // Note: No comma after final entry
    ];

    response = [];
    function setAnswer(question, answer) { response[question] = answer; }

    function CheckAnswers() {
      var correct = 0;
      var flag, resp, answ;
      for (var i = 0; i < answer_list.length; i++) {
        flag = false;
        for(var j=0; j<answer_list[i].length; j++){
          resp = response[i].toLowerCase();
          answ = answer_list[i][j].toLowerCase();
          if ((resp == answ) || (answ.indexOf(resp) != -1)) { flag = true; }
        }
        if (flag) {
          correct++;
          document.getElementById('ques'+i).style.backgroundColor = '1AFD1A';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('ques'+i).style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
        }
      }
    //  alert("You got " + correct + " of " + answer_list.length + " questions correct!");
    }
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Quiz</TITLE>
    <style type="text/css">
     .ques { width:50%; border:1px solid black; }
    </style>  
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR = #9DE4F2>
    <FONT FACE="Print bold" SIZE=10>Quiz</FONT><BR>
    <HR SIZE=9 WIDTH=100%>
    <FONT FACE="Print bold" SIZE=5>
    <FORM>

    <div id="ques0" class="ques">
    <B>1.  She <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=question0 size=30
    onChange="setAnswer(0, this.value)" autofocus="autofocus" id="xax"> a girl.</B>
    </div>
    <P><BR><P>

    <div id="ques1" class="ques">
    <B>2. "is", "am", "are" are:</B><P>
     <label><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=question1 VALUE="Present tense"
     onClick="setAnswer(1,this.value)">Present tense</label><BR>
     <label><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=question1 VALUE="Past tense"
     onClick="setAnswer(1,this.value)">Past tense</label><BR>
     <label><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=question1 VALUE="Present perfect tense"
     onClick="setAnswer(1,this.value)">Present perfect tense</label><BR>
     <label><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=question1 VALUE="Future tense"
     onClick="setAnswer(1,this.value)">Future tense</label>
    </div>
    <BR><P>

    <div id="ques2" class="ques">
    <b>3. He
    <input type="text" name="question2" size="30"
     onchange="setAnswer(2, this.value)"> a police.</b>
    </div>
    <p>

    <div id="ques3" class="ques">
    <b>4. We
    <input type="text" name="question2" size="30"
     onchange="setAnswer(3, this.value)"> friends.</b>
    </div>
    <p>

    <div id="ques4" class="ques">
    <b>5. I
    <input type="text" name="question2" size="30"
     onchange="setAnswer(4, this.value)"> happy</b>
    </div>
    <p>

    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="check" VALUE="Check Answers" onClick=CheckAnswers()>
    </FORM>
    </FONT>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Whatever tutorial you're using to build your HTML is way out of date. The capital letters on the tags, the `font` tag, inline style-like attributes, are all deprecated.

Comment: Finding a  starting place to help you is not simple since what you have right now is quite primitive. Not trying to be derogatory, just being real

Comment: Another issue is whether you need results captured or not. If so will require data storage beyond what the browser provides

Comment: @JoeEnos - Neither CAPS type names nor style attributes are deprecated. Just considered not-best-practice.

Comment: @Quentin You're right - looks like upper-case tags are allowed in HTML5, didn't realize that. Some of the other stuff like the `<font>` tags and attributes like `bgcolor`, `size` and `width` are showing up as "obsolete" in the [HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my recommendation:

*Note:* As mentioned in the comments, the HTML version you use for the page is deprecated. In the current HTML version (HTML5) you should strictly seperate style and semantics and therefore not use tags like `<b>` or the `<font>` tag. Style would be implemented using CSS.

### HTML

This would be the pure HTML code (I've left out the declarations of `doctype` etc.)

```
<div id="ques0" class="ques">
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <p>She
    <input type="text" name="answer0" /> a girl.</p>
</div>

<div id="ques1" class="ques">
  <h2>Question 2</h2>
  <p>"is", "am" and "are" are</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Present tense" />
      <label>Present tense</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Past tense" />
      <label>Past tense</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Future tense" />
      <label>Future tense</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="ques2" class="ques">
  <h2>Question 3</h2>
  <p>He
    <input type="text" name="answer2" /> a police.
  </p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:checkAnswer()">Check answer!</a>
```

As you see, this contains only the pure semantic. Each question is a `<div>` with its own `id`. The headlines of the questions are `<h2>` elements. The multiple choice question is realized using an unordered list (`<ul>`), containing the answer possibilites as list items (`<li>`).

The link (`<a>`) in the last line is used to trigger the program's code to check the answer.

If you want to change the style, you would use CSS (a css file can be embedded placing `<link rel="stylesheet" path="path/to/your/stylesheet.css" />` in the `head` section of the document).

### CSS

I won't say much about styling here, as it is not really part of the problem, but if you want you can read for example [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) about CSS on W3Schools.

Just one thing: If you want to remove the list bullets from the multiple choice questions, you would add

```
.ques ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

to your styles CSS file.

### JavaScript

JavaScript is a client-side programming language. Client-side means that everything is executed (and therefore loaded) in the client's browser. As a result your answers are not really "hidden" - if someone wants to cheat and knows a little about JavaScript, they could just open the developer console and view the source code.
As you only want to make a quiz for some students, I think JavaScript will do well.

If you want to create a competition (e.g. a high score list) or hide the answers, you have to use a server-side language like PHP (and probably a database like MariaDB accessed using SQL). This would make things more complicated, so I won't discuss them. If you want to learn more, I would again recommend having a look at W3Schools' sites - they have good tutorials for most of the popular web languages.

When using JavaScript, I would recommend embedding [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which makes it easier to modify web pages (what we'll need). Just download the current version (for example from here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js) and add it to your HTML site placing `<script src="/path/to/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` in the `head` section.

The script would have to perform several tasks:

1. (directly after window is loaded) Shuffle question order
2. Hide all questions except the one that is first in the shuffelled order
3. *Let the user answer the question*
4. (after "Check answer!" is clicked) Check answer
5. Display "right" or "wrong"
6. If the answer is wrong, repeat. If not, continue with step 7
7. If the answer is right and there are questions left, start over at step 2 (using the next question, of course). If there are no questions left, quit.

You could implement those tasks like this (all the following code could be placed inside a `<script>` tag in the `head` section):

```
window.onload = function() {
  // == Task 1: Shuffle question order ==
  var questionCnt = $("div.ques").length; // $ calls the jQuery function. It returns a list of elements that match the selector "div.ques" (which means, all divs with the ques class). We need the length of the list (the question count)
  questionOrder = []; // The order in which the questions will be shown
  while (questionOrder.length < questionCnt) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionCnt); // Get random number between 0 and the question count
    if (questionOrder.indexOf(rnd) == -1) questionOrder.push(rnd); // Add it to the question order, but only if it has not been added
    questionsAsked = 0; // The number of questions asked until now
    hideAllExcept(questionOrder[questionsAsked]); // Start: Hide all questions except one
  }
}

// == Used for Task 2: Hides all questions except the given one ==
function hideAllExcept(question) {
  $("div.ques").hide(); // Hides all questions
  $("#ques" + question).show(); // Shows only the given question
}

// The answers
var answers = [
  ["is", "was"],
  ["Present tense"],
  ["is", "was"]
];

// == Used for Task 4: Triggered by the link, checks an answer ==
function checkAnswer() {

  var questionNumber = questionOrder[questionsAsked]; // The number of the question that is shown at the moment
  var answer; // Get the answer

  if (questionNumber == 1) {
    answer = $("#ques" + questionNumber + " input:checked").val(); // Returns the value of the attribute "value" of the selected radio button
  } else {
    answer = $("#ques" + questionNumber + " input").val(); // The value of the input field that is placed in the given question
  }

  // Check whether the answer is correct
  var correct = answers[questionNumber].indexOf(answer) != -1;

  // Display a message
  window.alert(correct ? "Your answer is correct!" : "Sadly, your answer is not correct.");


  // Continue, if answer is correct
  if (correct) {
    questionsAsked++; //Increase questionsAsked
    if (questionsAsked >= questionOrder.length) {
      window.alert("Well done, you've completed the quiz!");
    } else {
      hideAllExcept(questionOrder[questionsAsked]); // Start over at step 2
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a jsfiddle with a live demo of the quiz: https://jsfiddle.net/ujLgarus/4/

This is just a draft, you can change it like you want to get the requested behavior. If you have questions, just post a comment on the answer - I'll try my best to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much!. it took a while for me to figure it out the code you gave me but finally it worked. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: But I have a few questions thou.

1). so about the css, does that mean whatever things that I want to do to make the quiz "looks good", like the styling, background color, width and height of the text box etc. will have to be put in the css file instead of the php or js files?

2). I want to make the cursor autofocus on the text box once the page is loaded, and I've found this: <input type=text"name="name" autofocus="autofocus" id=xax" />. However, it only works when the radomized quiz displays the 1st question and it only works for the 1st question but not the 3rd fill in the blank Q.

Comment: If it radamizes the question and the 1st question displayed in the quiz is not the 1st Q in the script, then the autofocus function won't work even if I've put the script to the 3rd question. Is there anyway to fix that? 

3) Is there anyway I can add a score at the end once the student finishes the quiz, and a timer for each question?

Comment: thanks a lot for answering all my questions! I'm still very new to programming but I'll try to best to learn it ASAP so our team can make the most effective quiz for our students with our self-created curriculum! Really appreciate you guys' effort in helping the future generation!

Comment: To your questions: 1.) Exact. Everything that changes the look has to be put in the CSS files. Have a look at csszengarden.com and try a few different styles. You'll see content (HTML) stays the same but appearance changes completely. All this is possible just with CSS.

Comment: 2.) Try inserting this at the the end of the `hideAllExcept` function: `$("#ques" + question + " input").focus()`. I haven' tried it yet, but it should work (note you probably have to treat the multiple choice questions differently, as focusing them might not work).

Comment: 3.) That should be possible. For the timer have a look at `setTimeout(function, time)` or `setInterval` which triggers a function after a given amount of time (there should be examples on W3Schools). For a (local) score add more variables to the JS (below `var answers`, for example), in which you store the facts you want. Update them in `checkAnswer()` so score will be checked every time a question is answered.

Comment: Now a little question from my side: When all your questions concerning this topic are answered, could you please mark my answer as accepted? This is used to show what answer helped you best (and it's quite how the StackOverflow community says thank you ;)). Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. It helps a lot! I have a new question. Is there anyway I can calculate the score for my fill in the blanks quiz? I saw a lot online about calculating score for multiple choice question but not for fill in the blanks. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I've understood that correctly; but you could use simple JavaScript variables to store a score and jQuery's [`.text(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) function to set the text of an read-only element (`p`, `span`, `div` etc.) or [`.val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to set the value of an input field.

Comment: Oh, and one thing: The concept of StackOverflow is a bit different to e.g. forums: Insted of opening a single thread for a problem, you often split up a problem in multiple questions about a small sub-problem. 
So, if you've got another problem building your quiz, you could create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a new question. Then you'll probably also get help from other community members (most of them don't look at the comments of answered questions ;)).